Console does not work in Pycharm 2024.1.2
Not long ago I installed Pycharm 2024.1.2 to replace Pycharm 2022. I start the console and it gives an error:
C:/python-3.12.3-embed-amd64\python.exe “C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py” --mode=client --host=127.0.0.0.1 --port=62166 
Traceback (last last last call):
  File “C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py”, line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle._pydev_getopt import gnu_getopt
ModuleNotFoundError: There is no module named '_pydev_bundle'
Failed to connect to the console process.
The process terminated with exit code 1

What is wrong and how to fix it?
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
Is the problem in the interpreter or in the application itself?
